# DB View creation with SQL methods to break in multiple columns

Tags: sql, database

I wanted to create view from my table which has a column Validity with the data in format (key-value). The view should has two columns called Key and Value.

```
Create view [dbo].[A_V_DATA_T]
as 
Select
SUBSTRING(dbo.Table1.Validity, 0, PATINDEX('%-%', dbo.Table1.Validity))
as Key,
SUBSTRING(dbo.Table1.Validity,
     PATINDEX('%-%', dbo.Table1.Validity) + 1, LEN(dbo.Table1.Validity) )
     as Value
from 
dbo.dbo.Table1
```

Is it correct/optimized way of doing it?  Is tehre any other method to achieve this effectively.

THanks
K2G

Comment: as for me, it is not a good idea to store key-value pair in one column at all. Anyway, as you know delimiter `-`, it better way to use `CHARINDEX()` instead of `PATINDEX()`.

Comment: That's legacy data and table which i don't have permission to change. So i am planning to rectify the same and planning to use view for further changes. I am doubtful about above query because i am using same function multiple times which can be avoided

Comment: just remember to materialize the view by creating index on it like 
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IndexName on A_V_DATA_T (Key, View)

Comment: perhaps `LEFT(value, CHARINDEX('-', dbo.Table1.Validity, 0) - 1)   AS [key]` is more efficient and readable code